# Can we use superposition of electric fields to conclude that between plates of capacitor the field is $2\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, gauss-law

Consider a parallel plate capacitor. This is a setup of two very large parallel plates, each a conductor and each with area $A$, and one having positive charge $Q$ and the other negative charge $-Q$.

My question is about the value of the electric field between these conductors.

Now, if these parallel plates were non conducting charged planes then we could compute the electric field due to each plate and use superposition.

By Gauss' Law using a pillbox as a Gaussian surface for one of the plates we have

$$E\cdot 2A = \frac{\sigma A}{\epsilon_0}$$

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$$

where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density on the plate.

When we use superposition we obtain a field of $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$ between the plates and zero elsewhere.

But what we really have are conductors, and conductors have no electric field inside of them. Thus, when we use Gauss' Law on one of the plates we have

$$EA=\frac{\sigma A}{\epsilon_0}$$

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$$

Now it seems to me that this calculation is the same whether there is a second plate or not. After all, the second plate generates a field that contributes zero flux on the pillbox we're using as a Gaussian surface.

On the other hand, why can't we use superposition to write the electric field at a point between the plates as

$$E=E_1+E_2=2\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$$

A quick google search for the electric field between capacitor plates gives me [this link](https://www.youphysics.education/parallel-plate-capacitor/), which shows a calculation that considers the plates as infinitely charged planes. So another way to frame my question, perhaps, is to ask why such calculations don't take into account the fact that we have conductors and the electric field inside of these conductors is zero?

Comment: It is unclear how the field inside one of the plates comes to play a role in your question. (And it shouldn't, really.) Perhaps you draw some of those pill boxes to clarify?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65191/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation for the case of a conducting plate,
$$EA=\frac{\sigma A}{\epsilon_0}$$
*can* be derived by taking a Gaussian pillbox with one end-disc inside the metal of a plate and the other end-disc in the gap between the plates, so flux *EA* emerges through the latter end-disc and no flux passes through the other end-disc or the sides. It assumes, does it not, that all the charge is residing on one side (the 'inner' side) of the plate so all the charge on area $A$ of plate lies inside the pillbox? This would not be so if the plate were 'isolated'; in that case the charge would distribute itself equally on each side of the plate.

So your Gauss's law equation actually assumes the presence of an equally and oppositely charged plate facing the first plate. You must not add to the first plate's field another field due to the second plate, because you have already taken into account the field due to the second plate, albeit indirectly.

Comment: I'd really like to know the reason for the downvote. Is it because my answer is thought to contain wrong Physics, or is thought not to answer the question, or is it unclear? I've expanded it a little to try and make it clearer.

Comment: You didn't answer the question, or add confusion: "So your Gauss's law equation actually assumes the presence of an equally and oppositely charged plate facing the first plate." Nowhere in the question is this to be found. Instead you assume things the OP did, while it is highly unclear where exactly he went wrong, as this happens in the vague part "But what we really have are conductors, and conductors have no electric field inside of them. Thus, when we use Gauss' Law on one of the plates we have..." Why not let him spell out this argument before taking it apart? Your edit is an improvement.

Comment: @ kricheli Thank you. "Nowhere in the question is this to be found." I thought that it was to be found in the equation itself, or was at least implied by the equation. Maybe Evianpring will comment.